# When are events in tail $\sigma$-algebra the limsup of some sequence of events?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Consider a sequence of $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{F}_1,\mathcal{F}_2,\dots$. Is it true that for any event $B$ in the tail $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F_{\text{Tail}}}$, it can be expressed as the $\limsup$ of some sequence of events $A_1,A_2,\dots$ such that $A_i \in \mathcal{F}_i$ for all $i$? Unfortunately, I have absolutely no intuition in this problem, and thus have no idea how to proceed.

Any help provided would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you define the tail $\sigma$-algebra to begin with - is this $\bigcap_n \sigma(\mathcal  F_n, \mathcal F_{n+1}, \dots)$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, let $\mathcal S_0=\{\{0,1\},\emptyset\}$ and let
$\mathcal S_1$ be the powerset of $\{0,1\}$. Let 
$\mathcal F_n=\mathcal S_0^{n-1}\times\mathcal S_1
\times\mathcal S_0^{\infty}$.

Let us write $X\in\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ as $(X_n)_n$.

Let $B=\{X:X_n=1$ for at most finitely many $n\}$. Suppose $B=$ lim sup $A_n$. Then

> $X_n=1$ for at most finitely many $n$
>   $\iff$ infinitely many $A_n$ occur.

Case 1: for infinitely many $n$, $A_n=\{0,1\}$.
Then $X_n=1$ for all $n$ is a counterexample.

I'll let you think about the other cases.

Comment: Which space are you talking about? First you say that all $\mathcal F_n$ are the  powerset of $\{0,1\}$, meaning that the state space is just the two-point set $\{0,1\}$. However, in the next sentence you are talking about subsets of the space of binary sequences.

Comment: I assume that each $X_n$ denotes the value of the $n^{\text{th}}$ number in the binary sequence. This is my attempt to show that $B$ is not the limsup of any $A_n$:

Suppose there are infinitely many $A_n$ such that $1 \in A_n$. Then since $\limsup{A_n}$ contains sequences that have infinitely many 1s, this choice is not possible. This means that for sufficiently large $N$, $A_n = \{0\}$ for $n \geq N$. This however excludes all sequences that have finitely many 1s but contains 1s after the $N^\text{th}$ digit. Therefore, no choice of $A_n$ is possible.

Am I correct?

Comment: @RW Thanks I think it may be fixed now

Comment: @yellowello I think you're right but you may want to write it more carefully (than I did)